# Counting powerful integers. Lower bounds

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, computational-number-theory

Remark:   *The upper bounds are perhaps still more interesting; I may address them in another post.*

---

**PROBLEM**:   Find simple (numerically efficient) lower bounds for the number of powerful integers (natural numbers) not exceeding an arbitrary positive real number $\ x;\ $ (let them be as precise as possible).

---

Of several equivalent definitions of powerful numbers, I like the following one, and it seems helpful in this note:

> A powerful integer $\ n\in\mathbb N\ $ is a product $\ n=a^2\cdot d\ $ where
> $\ a\in\mathbb N,\ $ and divisor $\ d|a\ $ is a square free natural number too.

This way $\ a=A(n)\ $ and $\ d=D(n)\ $ is uniquely determined by
$\ n\in\text{POW}\ $ -- the set of all powerful numbers.

---

We get two subsets of POW, namely squares and cubes, while the
intersection of the two consists of the sixth powers. Thus, let

$$ \text{POW}(x)\ :=\ \{\,n\in\text{POW}:\ n\le x\,\} $$

We get our first lower bound, as weak as it is:

$$ \left\lfloor x^\frac12\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor x^\frac13\right\rfloor
       - \left\lfloor x^\frac16\right\rfloor\ \le\,\ |\text{POW}(x)| $$

-- just for starters.

---

---

---

**PS**. Another equivalent definition of powerful integers:

**Definition**: natural number $\ n\in\mathbb N\ $ is powerful $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow$

$$ r^2(n)\, |\, n $$

where $\ r(n)\ $ is the radix of $\ n,\ $ i.e. the product of all prime divisors of $\ n.$

Comment: Actually, outside the above definition of powerful numbers, I know only two classical definitions; do you know more of them -- perhaps they can be mentioned here in the comments.

Comment: In OEIS's [A118896](https://oeis.org/A118896) (Number of powerful numbers <= 10^n), the second comment in the Comments section states "Bateman & Grosswald proved that the number of powerful numbers up to x is zeta(3/2)/zeta(3) * x^1/2 + zeta(2/3)/zeta(2) * x^1/3 + o(x^1/6). This approximates the series very closely: up to a(24), all absolute errors are less than 75." Thus, it seems that a reasonably good lower bound, especially for larger $x$ values, would be $\frac{\zeta(3/2)x^{1/2}}{\zeta(3)}+\frac{\zeta(2/3)x^{1/3}}{\zeta(2)}-cx^{1/6}$ for some relatively small constant $c \gt 0$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan, these integers are different from $\ x^2\cdot y^3.\ $ I was not able to find powerful numbers as:
$$ 1\ 4\ 8\ 9\ 16\ 25\ 27\ 36\ 49\ 64\ 72 \ldots $$
-- I tried in several different ways $\ (72=2^3\cdot3^2\ $ is the first "generic" term).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerful_number

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao, in. my comment I meant OEIS only, I knew about wikipedia. However, something has jinxed me since I got nowhere with OEIS. And, indeed, I overlooked a ref. to OEIS in the wikipedia. After your link, everything became "normal", thank you, I do see that seq. there and over. Once again, thank you.

Comment: I don't know what you're referring to. The Wikipedia article that StanleyYaoXiao indicated (which mentions the $x^2\cdot y^3$ form) has a link to OEIS [A001694](https://oeis.org/A001694) (that lists the powerful numbers), from which I got my link to OEIS [A118896](https://oeis.org/A118896). This other page gives *just* how many powerful numbers are $\le 10^n$. Looking at A001694, I see it matches, with $1$ for $1$ (i.e., $1$), $4$ for $10$ (i.e., $3$ more of $4$, $8$ and $9$) and $14$ for $100$ (i.e., with $10$ more of $16$, $25$, $27$, $32$, $36$, $49$, $64$, $72$, $81$ and $100$). ...

Comment: (cont.) I assume your comment reply to StanleyYaoXiao indicated you realized the issue but, if not, please let me know. Also, I believe my comment's referenced paper of [On a theorem of Erdös and Szekeres](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-2/issue-1/On-a-theorem-of-Erd%c3%b6s-and-Szekeres/10.1215/ijm/1255380836.full) gives about a tight a bound, both lower & upper, i.e., of $o(x^{1/6})$, as you can reasonably expect to get on how many powerful numbers there are up to $x$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan, many thanks for your comments (and to Staanley Yao Xiao too). I'll try to digest them.

Comment: $4=2^21^3$. $8=1^22^3$. So, yes, the $x^2y^3$ definition is correct. Another equivalent definition is that for all primes $p$, if $p$ divides $n$, then $p^2$ divides $n$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, the $\ p\to p^2\ $ and $\ x^2\cdot y^3\ $ are the classical, common definitions. Here, I have added two more (and each for a good reason). BTW, after my last definition, another ugly guy had to commit his filthy deed and has cowardly down-voted my post.

Comment: I thought you were disputing the $x^2y^3$ definition, on the grounds that you couldn't get anything less than $72$ using it. Also, you asked for "more" definitions, without telling anyone which ones you already knew – was I meant to read your mind? And could you please stop whining about downvotes? It's not very becoming. (And, no, I haven't downvoted.)

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I do NOT whine! (And I never said that you've down-voted my post above).

Comment: In my response below, I recorded the numerical upper and lower bounds of Golomb (1970).

Answer (score 4):

[Golomb (1970)](https://doi.org/10.2307%2F2317020) proved that for all $x\geq 1$ we have
$$\frac{\zeta(3/2)}{\zeta(3)}x^{1/2}-3x^{1/3}\ \leq\ \left|\mathrm{POW}(x)\right|\ \leq\ \frac{\zeta(3/2)}{\zeta(3)}x^{1/2}.$$
Note that
$$\frac{\zeta(3/2)}{\zeta(3)}=2.1732543125195541382370898404\dots$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It looks that my own (unsophisticated :) ) answer is not too far off. Can you make a clean comparison of the two? (I did only the lower bound though).

Comment: GHfromMO, why 1? I have a bit different function; otherwise, my bound is something like $\ 4*x^{\frac12}\times (1-\frac 1{log(x)}) hence it looks even better than 2++ but for a little more generous function.

Comment: @WlodAA For $x>10^9$, your lower bound $\left\lfloor x^\frac12\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor x^\frac13\right\rfloor
       - \left\lfloor x^\frac16\right\rfloor$ is less than 1/2 of Golomb's lower bound.

Comment: A lower bound that is asymptotically $4x^{1/2}$ is false. Just look at Golomb's upper bound (in my post).

Comment: GHfromMO, you're looking at my OP post rather than at my "Answer", am I right?

Comment: @WlodAA I am looking at your original post concerning $\mathrm{POW}(x)$. In general, the question is supposed to be in the original post, and I am supposed to look at that.

Comment: GHfromMO, r u talking math or about some fictitious legal procedures of you own creation?! An Answer is an answer! A question is a question. Try to have some self-respect!

Comment: @WlodAA Your question (or rather, request) was the following. "Find simple (numerically efficient) lower bounds for the number of powerful integers (natural numbers) not exceeding an arbitrary positive real number $x$." Golomb (1970) gave a lower bound, and I reproduced it in my answer. For $x>10^9$, this lower bound by Golomb (1970) is more than twice your lower bound $\left\lfloor x^\frac12\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor x^\frac13\right\rfloor        - \left\lfloor x^\frac16\right\rfloor$.

Comment: GHfromMO, why 1? I have a bit different function; otherwise, my bound is something like $\ 4\cdot x^{\frac12}\cdot (1-\frac 1{log(x)})$ hence it looks even better than 2++ but for a little more generous function. That my modification of the function seems to be the right way to approach this topic.

Comment: @WlodAA As I told you earlier, the lower bound $3.99\cdot x^{1/2}$ for $|\mathrm{POW}(x)|$ is false, because $2.18\cdot x^{1/2}$ is an upper bound. The upper bound takes one line to prove, and it is given in Golomb's article. I did not look at your $\mathrm{PWR}(x)$ as your original post did not concern that. If you want to ask a question about $\mathrm{PWR}(x)$, create a new post for it.

Comment: @WlodAA I am not playing games. In general, MathOverflow is a question-and-anwer site. One asks a question (one question per post), and others can answer it. Your original post was about $\mathrm{POW}(x)$. Golomb's article has an approach to it via Dirichlet series which is the best known tool to approach such questions. If you want to ask about $\mathrm{PWR}(x)$, open a new question for it. This is not a game but how this site and this community works. If you don't like it or you don't fit in, that's your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It has occurred to me that I can get a much more decent lower bound but for a somewhat different function $\ \text{PWR}(x);\ $ it is still closely related to $\ \text{POW}(x).\ $ The new definition takes an advantage of function $\ A(n)\ $ as in the OP post, where
$$ \forall_{n\in\text{POW}}\qquad
  n\ =\ A^2(n)\cdot D(n)\qquad $$
with $\ D(n)\ $ being a square-free divisor of $\ A(n),\ $ i.e.
$\ D(n)|A(n).$ Thus, let's define:

$$ \text{PWR}(x)\ :=\ \{\,n\in \text{PWR}:\ A^2(n)\le x\,\} $$

Obviously

$$ |\text{POW}(x)|\ \le\ |\text{PWR}(x)|\ \le
  \ \left|\text{POW}\left(x^\frac32\right)\right| $$

Now we obtain:

$$ 4\cdot\left\lfloor x^\frac12\right\rfloor\ -\ 2\cdot
 \Pi\left(\left\lfloor x^\frac12\right\rfloor\right)
 \,\ \le\ \,\ |\text{PWR}(x)| $$

where $\ \Pi(t)\ $ is the very well-behaved function that counts
prime powers that do not exceed positive $\ t\in\mathbb R.$

The left-hand side counts only powerful integers $\ n\ $ such that
$\ D(n)\ $ is a product of at the most $\ 2\ $ primes $ \ p\ne q\ $ that both divide $\ A(n);\ $ however, for the sake of this simple counting, we select just a single pair of such two primes (when they exist) -- that's how you get $\ 4\ $ and $\ 2\ $
in the above inequality; **indeed**, for each prime power
$\ A(n):=p^k\ $ we get only 2 powerful *extensions*
$\ n=p^{2\cdot k}\ $, and $\ n=p^{2\cdot k+1}.\ $ However, when
$\ A(n)\ $ is divisible by at least two different primes, say
$\ p\ $ and $\ q\ $, then we get at least $\ 2^2\ $ different
extensions:
$$ A^2(n)\quad\text{and}\quad A^2(n)\cdot p\quad\text{and}\quad
 A^2(n)\cdot q\quad\text{and}\quad A^2(n)\cdot p\cdot q $$
Of course, when the number of prime divisors of $\ A(n)=r\ $
then we get $\ 2^r\ $ extensions of $\ A(n).\ $ Thus, each time when
$\ r>2\ $ we get more extensions than just $\ 2^2=4\ $ but it's hard
(for me) to take a full advantage of this fact.

Comment: So cynical and sick, here and above, those stupid down-votes.